# How to plot a line made by the touching points of two function?

Tags: plotting, graphics

[image]suppose we have the functions f[x,y] and g[x,y] defined as,

```
en[J2_,J3_,x_,y_]:=Abs[Re[Eigenvalues[{{(2*J2+1-J3),0,J3,0,0,J2,Exp[I*x],J2},{0,(2*J2+1-J3),0,J3,J2,0,J2,Exp[I*y]},{J3,0,(2*J2+1-J3),0,Exp[-I*x],J2,0,J2},{0,J3,0,(2*J2+1-J3),J2,Exp[-I*y],J2,0},{0,-J2,-Exp[I*x],-J2,-(2*J2+1-J3),0,-J3,0},{-J2,0,-J2,-Exp[I*y],0,-(2*J2+1-J3),0,-J3},{-Exp[-I*x],-J2,0,-J2,-J3,0,-(2*J2+1-J3),0},{-J2,-Exp[-I*y],-J2,0,0,-J3,0,-(2*J2+1-J3)}}]]];

f[x_,y_]:=en[3.,2.,x,y][[1]];
g[x_,y_]:=en[3.,2.,x,y][[3]];
```

How to plot the contour formed by (x,y) points where the functions f[x,y] touches with g[x,y]? I had tried by the following command,

```
ContourPlot[f[x,y]==g[x,y],{x,-Pi,Pi},{y,-Pi,Pi},PlotPoints->100];
```

But I failed.
Someone please help me how to fix it.
I have added the 3d plot of f and g which shows the touching of the two function.

Comment: `ContourPlot` shows a circle. What means "But I failed"?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Actually in my problem the two functions f and g are two eigenvalues out of 8 eigenvalues of a 8*8 matrix. the functions do not have any analytical expressions. We have to do it numerically. In the above question I have used those expressions for simplicity to know whether there is any other way to do it. In my main problem I had used the same contourplot command, but failed. I am very sorry as the description for the question seems misleading.

Comment: For the given functions ContourPlot gives the right answer?

Comment: Yes. That is fine. In my problem the matrix is en[J2_,J3_,x_,y_]:=Abs[Re[Eigenvalues[{{(2*J2+1-J3),0,J3,0,0,J2,Exp[I*x],J2},{0,(2*J2+1-J3),0,J3,J2,0,J2,Exp[I*y]},{J3,0,(2*J2+1-J3),0,Exp[-I*x],J2,0,J2},{0,J3,0,(2*J2+1-J3),J2,Exp[-I*y],J2,0},{0,-J2,-Exp[I*x],-J2,-(2*J2+1-J3),0,-J3,0},{-J2,0,-J2,-Exp[I*y],0,-(2*J2+1-J3),0,-J3},{-Exp[-I*x],-J2,0,-J2,-J3,0,-(2*J2+1-J3),0},{-J2,-Exp[-I*y],-J2,0,0,-J3,0,-(2*J2+1-J3)}}]]];ContourPlot[en[3.,2.,x,y][[1]]==en[3.,2.,x,y][[3]],{x,-Pi,Pi},{y,-Pi,Pi},PlotPoints->100]    In this case it is not working!

Comment: Change `Ix-> I x` `Iy-> I y
`

Comment: You should modify your question to  show your complete problem!

Comment: I have written I*x in the matrix. It became Ix while copying from mathematica file. And thanks for your advice. I am going to edit my question to remove all the confusions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Clear["Global`*"]
```

There were still a couple of typos ("Ix", "Iy")

```
en[J2_, J3_, x_, y_] := 
 Abs[Re[Eigenvalues[{{(2*J2 + 1 - J3), 0, J3, 0, 0, J2, Exp[I*x], 
      J2}, {0, (2*J2 + 1 - J3), 0, J3, J2, 0, J2, Exp[I*y]}, {J3, 
      0, (2*J2 + 1 - J3), 0, Exp[-I*x], J2, 0, J2}, {0, J3, 
      0, (2*J2 + 1 - J3), J2, Exp[-I*y], J2, 
      0}, {0, -J2, -Exp[I*x], -J2, -(2*J2 + 1 - J3), 0, -J3, 0}, {-J2, 
      0, -J2, -Exp[I*y], 0, -(2*J2 + 1 - J3), 0, -J3}, {-Exp[-I*x], -J2, 
      0, -J2, -J3, 0, -(2*J2 + 1 - J3), 0}, {-J2, -Exp[-I*y], -J2, 0, 0, -J3, 
      0, -(2*J2 + 1 - J3)}}]]]
```

Keep exact values as long as possible

```
f[x_, y_] = en[3, 2, x, y][[1]] // FullSimplify;

g[x_, y_] = en[3, 2, x, y][[3]] // FullSimplify;
```

For highly complicated expressions, use arbitrary-precision (specify `WorkingPrecision`) rather than using machine precision.

```
ContourPlot[f[x, y] == g[x, y],
 {x, -Pi, Pi}, {y, -Pi, Pi},
 PlotPoints -> 100,
 WorkingPrecision -> 15]
```

[image]

**EDIT:** It is not clear how you arrived at your 3D plots

```
plt3d = Plot3D[{f[x, y], g[x, y]},
  {x, -Pi, Pi}, {y, -Pi, Pi},
  PlotPoints -> 100,
  WorkingPrecision -> 15,
  PlotLegends -> "Expressions"]
```

[image]

**EDIT 2:** It appears that the ordering of the `Eigenvalues` is affected by whether `en` is evaluated with exact or approximate numbers.

```
Table[en[3, 2, x, y][[n]], {n, 8}] /. {x -> 0, y -> 0}

(* {0, 0, 2 Sqrt[2], 2 Sqrt[2], 2 Sqrt[2], 2 Sqrt[2], 2 Sqrt[6], 2 Sqrt[6]} *)

(Table[en[3., 2., x, y][[n]], {n, 8}] /. {x -> 0, y -> 0}) // 
  Chop[#, 10^-7] & // RootApproximant

(* {2 Sqrt[6], 2 Sqrt[2], 2 Sqrt[2], 0, 0, 2 Sqrt[2], 2 Sqrt[2], 2 Sqrt[6]} *)
```

Consequently, the definition of `en` is not numerically stable.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But this is not the correct plot. In the given plotrange there will be only one square due to touching of f and g. the square will pass through points (Pi,0),(0,Pi),(-Pi,0) and (0,-Pi).  It is very easy to see it by plotting a 3D plot of f and g.

Comment: It is very surprising that removing "FullSimplify" gives my 3D plot and including it gives your 3d plot ! I have screenshot of both plots but unable to find how to attach it in this comment!

Comment: I copied and pasted my code above, removed the `FullSimplify` from the definitions for `f` and `g`, and reran the plots. I got the same results that I show above. I am using v12.1 on macOS 10.15.4

Comment: But I have used same matrix followed by the commands , f[x_, y_] := en[3, 2, x, y][[1]];
g[x_, y_] := en[3, 2, x, y][[3]]; Plot3D[{f[x, y], g[x, y]}, {x, -Pi, Pi}, {y, -Pi, Pi}]; fp[x_, y_] = en[3, 2, x, y][[1]] // FullSimplify; gp[x_, y_] = en[3, 2, x, y][[3]] // FullSimplify; Plot3D[{fp[x, y], gp[x, y]}, {x, -Pi, Pi}, {y, -Pi, Pi}]; It is strange that again I am getting same as mentioned before. Anyway your answer was useful. Without 'FullSimplify' it gives correct result as I expected. Only I need to increase the plotpoints to remove all the discontinuities in the contour. Thanks you.